# What is the attr attribute of <a> tag?

Tags: html

I came across the tag `<a attr="idx0" title="Youku" href="http://www.youku.com/">Youku</a>` and I don't know what the attribute `attr` is. I have searched for it for hours but I still can't find it. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an attribute. The site where you have noticed it just defines such custom attribute and probably accesses it with JavaScript.